# allowsediting move and scale doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

This is my code for.m

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

for.h
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)takePhoto:  (UIButton *)sender;
```

However when I try to move to scale it bounces back to the center so i can't even crop anything.